# getparameter call from Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I'm learning Jquery these days and came across a doubt about submitting the data. Let's consider the below example

JSP:

```
<body>
<form name="newForm" id="newForm" action="getData" method="get">
<input type="name"/>
<input type="button" onclick="submit()"/>
</form>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function submit(){
document.getElementById("newForm").submit();
}
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
String x = request.getParameter("name");
system.out.println("Received name is "+ x);
}
```

When I run the above program, the console prints the values correctly.

I run the same using Jquery and the code is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form1").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : "getData",
            success : function(msg) {
                $('#header').append("Hi");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And nothing happens. Here my question is, should I necessarily send the name in the `data` or can it work like as in JavaScript, i.e. without sending the parameter it will pick the data?

In simple, to get parameters from a JSP in Servlet with an Ajax/Jquery call do i need to force send the parameters in `data`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard form submit() method simply submits the form via the browser - the same as clicking the button without a click event bound, therefore it is not submitting the form asynchronously.

For your JQuery example you need to bind a 'submit' event to the form in order to prevent it's default behaviour and submit the form asynchronously.

In order to pass the same data in the request as your first example, you will also need to serialise the form.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#newForm").on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "getData",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(msg) {
        $('header').append("Hi");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }).submit();
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgh97b6h/1/